# Diff between command > and command 1> ,>>

Tags: io-redirection

I am little bit confused about redirections in linux.

1. `command > file`
2. `command 1> file`
3. `command >> file.out 2>> file.err` (this is working as expected)
4. `commmand 1>>file.out 2>>file.err`  (if command is successful , we get output log of command in file.err instead of in file.out

some guys said > and 1> are same but when used with commands not getting proper output.

for example ,

```
pg_dump -d postgres -t schemaname.table -v -f table.sql   >>table.out 2>>table.err
```

if I execute above command , if command is successful , it should log the logs to `table.log` and not in `table.err` .
`table.err` we get logs only in case `pg_dump` status exit 1.

My expectation is we get log in `table.out` when `pg_dump` executed without any error while dumping tables.  and we  should get logs in `table.err` when `pg_dump` status is exit 1 or it's failed to dump tables.

Thanks!

Comment: I get right results - please post real command that you use when you get this behaviour.
To the other part of your question '>' and '1>' - as I know they are the same.

Comment: https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial will answer all your concerns.

Comment: _"not getting proper output"_ ... so, what would the proper output be, in this particular case? What output do you expect to get, and what do you get instead? What does `command` do? We could explain what `>`, `1>`, `>>` and `1>>` do, and quote the [manuals](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) and the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07), but I wonder if it would help more to be able to tie that to your situation.

Comment: I think you don't understand what stderr is. It's not just for "logs only in case pg_dump status exit 1" - applications are free to use stderr for informational or diagnostic logging, prompts, and other things.

Comment: You need to read a basic book about unix and do the programming samples, at least to some degree. theres all kind of fundamentals that you need to understand to start programming.